# ef4 map model defined function to property

Tags: .net-4.0, entity-framework-4, ef4-code-only

I've seen model defined functions used in in-code queries (queries written by the developer using Linq etc) and I'm wondering if there's any way to map a model-defined function to an entity property so that EF4 will automatically query the database using it.

For example:

Suppose I have a `Product` class and an `Order` class and that `Product` has a `TotalSold` property.    Ideally I would like to create a model defined function like:

`select sum(o.quantity) from order, product where o.productid = product.productid`

and bind that to the `TotalSold` property of `Product` so that every query for a given `Product` would auto generate an inner select that would populate the `TotalSold` property.

Does this make sense?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good-enough solution and blogged about it at http://statichippo.com/archive/2011/01/26/Mapping-a-computed-property-in-EF4.aspx

Comment: Nice job. I was hoping that the work discussed in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/01/07/model-defined-functions.aspx would have been made production quality in EF 4 or 4.1. I'm going to keep looking for something that says it is ...